# I can't find a quote in [class.copy.elision] confirming that the initialization `T x = T();` is eligible for the mandatory copy elision

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, copy-elision

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) cites two cases for the **Mandatory elision of copy/move operations**. I'm interested in the second case as follows:

> In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is
>   a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the
>   variable type.

Thus, the initialization below will have mandatory elision of the copy operation:

```
T x = T();
```

In fact, this initialization doesn't compile in C++14 when T's copy constructor is deleted, but it does compile in C++17 (see [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd26ab5bec62dcdc)), as stated in cppreference.com.

But I can't find a quote in [[class.copy.elision]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision) supporting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the wording is in [[dcl.init]/17.6.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1)

> - Otherwise, if the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the
>       destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the
>       destination object. [ Example: `T x = T(T(T()))`; calls the T default
>       constructor to initialize x. — end example ]

Guaranteed copy elision involved a clever alteration of the way value categories behave and interact. So it's spread across several places in the standard. You can see them by examining the [original proposal](http://wg21.link/p0135)